# Swift - Send notification 3 hours before its due

Tags: swift3

I have a local notification and I am wondering how I can send that notification 3 hours before midnight.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Dont Forget"
    content.body = "Test"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: datePicker.date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```